# mod_rewrite RedirectPermanent from root to new directory with same filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wan't to do a simple thing: redirect some urls. This works when I change the filename

RedirectPermanent /locations.html http://www.example.com/blog/xxx.html

But if they have the same filename it produces a 404 error:

RedirectPermanent /locations.html http://www.example.com/blog/locations.html

I now there is a solution for redirecting all urls from root to new directory, but I want to do this only for some urls.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `RedirectMatch` to be able to use regex in your regex matching:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(locations\.html)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1
```

Make sure this is your first rule in your root .htaccess and you clean your browser cache.